# Not able to read an XML file in a directory?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, iis

I have an MVC web application where I would like to read an XML file that will give me a list of image folders/files to display.

I'm running this locally on a Windows 10 machine using Visual Studio 2015. In my controller when I try to do the following code to get the XML file I immediately get an error `"The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory."`

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    XElement xelement = XElement.Load("~\\Gallery\\Gallery.xml");
    IEnumerable<XElement> galleries = xelement.Elements();

    return View();
}
```

I then did some research and found that I should put the following in my web.config file. When I do that and go to the View it will immediately just list out the folders in my directory.

```
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

I also followed some info where I went to IIS, selected Directory Browsing, and then "enable". That didn't seem to have any effect.

Any ideas on what I can do?

Error Message
[image]

Comment: Returning a view has nothing to do with parsing an xml file which in turn has nothing to do with directory browsing.  How are you calling your Index route and when exactly do you receive that error message?

Comment: This is the link to my View and the ActionResult in my original post is the Index it goes to. <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Gallery")">Click here</a>

Comment: I get the error message immediatley when I click on the link. I put a breakpoint at the beginning of the ActionResult and it never gets there unless I comment any code dealing with XML or FileSystem. If I comment that code it will go to the View otherwise it's the error message. If I put the code in web.config from above then when you click on the link it will immediately list the folders in the Gallery folder never hitting the breakpoint.

Comment: Screenshot of error added to post.

Answer (score 2):

`"~\\Gallery\\Gallery.xml"` is not understood as the path you intended by `XElement.Load`.

You can map ASP.NET application paths to file-system paths with [`HostingEnvironment.MapPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx), so:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~\\Gallery\\Gallery.xml"));
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure that is correct, however, I still get the error message about directory browsing unless I remove any code referring to XML or FileSystem. I initially was going to do a Directory.Getfiles and list out the folders and then the files with the folders.

Comment: Does the user account that your website is running under have access to that folder

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an Answer to this question in case someone else comes across the same issue.

The problem ended up being the fact that I had a controller named "Gallery" as well as a folder in my site called "Gallery". My HTML ActionLink was creating a hyperlink like  instead of . Once I changed the image folder to GalleryImages then everything worked properly.

Don't name your controllers the same as a folder name in your site.